# How did experiments affect the development of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, history

What were some of the major experiments that helped to develop Quantum Mechanics? I've read about the Stern-Gerlach experiment and double-slit experiment. But what role did experiments play? Did they act as motivation for understanding QM or act as verification of theories?

Comment: For something like a complete answer to this question, you can do no better than to read Abraham Pais's book "Inward Bound".

Comment: This question is really much too broad for this format - and it is well addressed by a myriad of introductory textbooks at a range of different levels.

Comment: Even if limited to the early days this covers about thirty years and dozens of landmark events. Seems t0o much of a Big List.